# Eloquent Model "UPDATE" Query Failing

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

i seem to have run into a rather obscure issue in which my Eloquent model's "update" query is not working anymore.

here's the query builder:

```
$os = OrderShipment::where('order_id', '=', $shipment->orderReferenceNumber)->update(array("api_shipment_id" => $data->shipmentId));
```

this query is inside an IF and so will only execute if $shipment->orderReferenceNumber has a value--which it does. this update query is always returning a false/0 updated rows.

inside of the OrderShipment model i have:

```
protected $fillable = [
        'api_shipment_id',
        'order_id',
        'shipping_method_id'
];
```

so the value is updatable and within the "fillable" array. i've also made sure that i can use a select statement with the 'order-id' and find the data via that--but no dice there either. the query works just fine if i do it from within a MySQL console, however, so i'm just kind of stuck here right now.

Comment: If nothing is modified, then it will return false/0 because no rows have been modified.

Comment: the thing i find odd about it is that the query works fine if i don't insert a variable and just pass a static var, such as manually inputting '1979' in place of '$shipment->orderReferenceNumber'--but i know that $shipment->orderReferenceNumber is defined and set, so this just flat out stumps me.

Comment: Is it defined, and set, `and different than what was already there`?  The key is that it needs to be different than what's already set or MySQL will report no rows changed even though the query itself was valid and successful.

Comment: yes, it's different, the current value is NULL, and i've tried changing it to random things to see if NULL was the issue; which it was not. if i use a "GET" statement to try to get the shipment by the order_id using the variable, it returns a blank/null/undefined variable.

Comment: That is strange!  What's the data type of the column in question?

Comment: it's of type int(11).

Answer (score 1):

i think below code can help you.

```
$os = OrderShipment::where('order_id', $shipment->orderReferenceNumber)->update([ "api_shipment_id" => $data->shipmentId ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solutions:

For **single** update:

```
$os = OrderShipment::where('order_id', $shipment->orderReferenceNumber)
$os->api_shipment_id = $data->shipmentId;
$os->update();
```

For **mass** updates:

```
OrderShipment::where('order_id', $shipment->orderReferenceNumber)
    ->update(["api_shipment_id" => $data->shipmentId]);
```

More info about [update](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#updates)